# Hard drive failing, trouble with MHDD

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

I'm dealing with failing WD 750 GB laptop hdd. Scan perfmormed with MHDD booted from flash disk indicated few (about 6) bad sectors.

Data on the hdd is not important, however I would like to still use this disk.

S.M.A.R.T data of the disk : http://pastebin.com/zA6UqMCP

I've found a tutorial that suggested 'zeroing' the drive with use of MHDD "ERASE" command and then remapping the drive; it was supposed to allow disk to work again by skipping bad sectors logically.

After about hour or two (of estimated 150), ERASE process resulted in "Catastrophical Error", with adnotation of "Broken drive".

Not being sure if there's anything more to be done, I've launched another scan with "remapping" the drive; when process encountered the first bad sector, the following happened: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/2784/o8c2.jpg.

"Blue" blocks are supposed indicate a remap attempt. Looks like it's the first bad sector that MHDD tried to remap.

Given above data, I would like to ask:

1. Do this data (especially SMART results) indicate that disk is already critically damaged and unusable at all?
2. Is there a way to get this hdd working again for short period of time (propably by skipping damaged sectors)?

I'll take any questions about facts relevant, yet not inclued here.

EDIT:
Thread that I'm suposedly duplicating suggests using HDD Regenerator (I did it - failed to make difference here) and Spinrite (which I've failed to run due to other issues).
This question is bit broader in scope.

Comment: Your drive has already remapped 133 blocks due to physical damage/failure.  It's (probably) run out of spare blocks and so the drive is un-trustable now (at best).  IMO, get your data off (if you care) and throw it out.

Comment: Isn't the "133" just standarized value of Remaped Sectors, where the "Raw" should really count as a actual number of those sectors?

Comment: "Too broad" actually IMO (which is a reason to close questions here on SU).  You need to narrow it down to a specific question (that's not already been asked).  If your narrowed question is "how do I avoid bad blocks to use this drive a little longer", then it's the same question (even if the answers don't suit you).  If you'd like newer/better answers to that question, earn some [Rep](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and post a [bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the original.

Comment: @Ponyman - If multiple tools are failing and the S.M.A.R.T data indicate the HDD  is not in a healthy state its time to replace the drive.  You don't indicate what tutorial you followed.

Comment: Rep limitations prevented me from including tutorial link. This tutorial is in polish language. http://www.nirvanowiec.republika.pl/MHDD.html

Comment: @Ponyman - in any event your HDD should be replaced.

Comment: The drive is strongly resisting your attempts to restore it.  It will likely take you at least 10 more hours of your time to restore this drive to trustworthy functionality.  New 750GB drives are on Newegg for about USD$80.00.  Thus, restoring this drive only makes sense if your time is worth USD$8.00/hour or less.  Otherwise, throw the drive on the recycling heap and get a new one.